# Example application Om next

Tags: clojurescript, om, om-next

is there any small example application in On next with GraphQL backend (few pages, queries and mutations)?

I'm doing presentation about Sangria (Scala GraphQL server library) and I want some frontend for it. And also I'm curious about Om for longer time.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://untangled-web.github.io/untangled/ - it might have example apps in tutorials.

Comment: Looks there is TodoMVC thanks!

Comment: Untangled has morphed and expanded to Fulcro. Check it out: https://fulcrologic.github.io/fulcro/